# Fatal error encountered during command execution using the same MySQLCommand

Tags: sql, vb.net

I'm using `MySQLCommand` to check if a certain field entered by user is correct or not. In this code below, I check if the user is already registered in the database. Now the email check working well but when I try to check the  username field I get this error:

> Fatal error encountered during command execution

**Code:**

```
Using dbCon As MySqlConnection = establishConnection()

        Try

            dbCon.Open()

            Dim query As String = "SELECT Count(email) from users WHERE email = @emailp"
            Dim MysqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(query, dbCon)

            With MysqlCommand.Parameters
                .AddWithValue("@emailp", email)
                .AddWithValue("@usernamep", username)
            End With

            Dim count = MysqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()

            If Convert.ToUInt32(count) > 0 Then
                MessageBox.Show("User already registered")
                exists = True
            End If

            query = "SELECT Count(username) from user_settings WHERE username = @usernamep"

            MysqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(query, dbCon)  

            count = MysqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()

            If Convert.ToInt32(count) > 0 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Username already exists")
                exists = True
            End If

        Catch myerror As MySqlException

            MessageBox.Show(myerror.Message)

        Finally

            dbCon.Dispose()

        End Try
    End Using
```

How you can see I'm using the same `MysqlCommand` object for perform the query, what am I doing wrong in this code?

Comment: where you got the error ?? I guess in the second `MysqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()` ??

Comment: Yes, as I said in the topic "When I check the username field" .. BUt the problem is solved now, thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding two parameters to the first command even if the second belongs to the second query. So remove it from the first and add it to the second:

```
Dim query As String = "SELECT Count(email) from users WHERE email = @emailp"
Dim MysqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(query, dbCon)
With MysqlCommand.Parameters
    .AddWithValue("@emailp", email)
End With
Dim count = MysqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()

' .... '

query = "SELECT Count(username) from user_settings WHERE username = @usernamep"
MysqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(query, dbCon)  ' this clears also the parameters previously added '
With MysqlCommand.Parameters
   .AddWithValue("@usernamep", username)
End With
count = MysqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()
```

Comment: So I can't add two parameter and reusing it in the next time? Now seems working, thanks, have a good day :)

Comment: @Jss: you are creating a new `MySqlCommand` with `New MySqlCommand`. Of course that will also clear the parameters that you have added to the first.

Comment: But is possible use the same MySqlCommand and specify the new query?

Comment: @Jss: that's bad practise, by creating a new instance you ensure that you don't get any unwanted side effects like wrong paramers, values or queries. So either use another `MySqlCommand` variable or do it like you've done it and create a new instance.

Comment: Okay I think that reacreate the object is a good way, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You need no to create `MysqlCommand` object  each time, just clear the parameter(s) and add the new one(s) just like below

```
dbCon.Open()
Dim query As String = "SELECT Count(email) from users WHERE email = @emailp"
Dim MysqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(query, dbCon)
MysqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emailp", email)
Dim count = MysqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()

            /* Your code*/

 query = "SELECT Count(username) from user_settings WHERE username = @usernamep"
 MysqlCommand.CommandText = query /* <- assigning new select query */
 MysqlCommand.Parameters.Clear() /*'<-- just clear the existing parameter */
 MysqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usernamep", username)/*'<- add new one*/
 count = MysqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()
```